# Why does far call "call far ptr label" MASM syntax not work as intended?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, function-call, memory-segmentation

I have been trying to set up a **0x9A**, absolute far call using **MASM** syntax in 32 bit mode and despite my code assembling succesfully, the result will always be `call far 0:0`. The valid MASM syntax `call far ptr label` seems to always zero the operands (9A 00000000 0000). I couldn't find an answer for this online. I have tried calling a label like this from different ".code" pages and the result is always `call far 0:0`. Why does it always nullify the operands?

All of my programs are based off the same .model type "`flat, stdcall`" and `option casemap` is set to :none.

```
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none

.code one

main proc far

call far ptr label_   ; intended MASM syntax for 0x9A call
call ExitProcess
main endp

.code two 

label_ proc far 

retf
label_ endp

end main
```

Which still assembles to

```
9A 00000000 0000   call far 0:0
E8 F4EFFFFF        call <project2._ExitProcess@4>
0000               add byte ptr ds:[eax],al
0000               add byte ptr ds:[eax],al
0000               add byte ptr ds:[eax],al
```

Comment: Far addressing doesn't apply to flat model.

Comment: For a far call/jump in protected mode, MASM would have to get a numerical segment selector value (index into GDT or LDT, and privilege level in low bits) from somewhere.  The correct value depends on the OS, and isn't documented or guaranteed stable AFAIK, and you haven't told MASM what number to use.  So even if it did support far calls in 32-bit code, I think you'd need some kind of `assume` directive. Some OSes have system calls to create a custom LDT entry (e.g. Linux https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/modify_ldt.2.html) which could let you set up a known integer segment selector.

Comment: But IDK why you'd want to do that. A normal `call rel32` (near call) can reach any 32-bit address from anywhere, so you don't need (or normally want) a `far` call between different `.code` sections.

Comment: hi @PeterCordes, I was expecting MASM to decode it as `9A XXXXXXXX 2300` with 0x23 being the default CS value in 32 bit legacy mode and XXXXXXXX being the 32 bit offset of the function (label_). This is indeed a near call in fact. My goal would be to find a way to call any function I want without knowing the segment value from beforehand. What @MichaelPetch said also makes sense. I switched to ".model LARGE" and something interesting happened: It assembled it to `call far 9A:0` which still doesn't make sense and crashed of course.

Comment: It used `9A` as the segment selector?  That's also the opcode.  Sounds very weird.  Anyway, re: calling any function you want without knowing the segment value: you can already do that with `near` calls.  Segmentation doesn't increase the size of address-space: linear addresses are still 32-bit, so segment_base + offset still wraps at 32-bit.  (Before virtual to physical).  If you expect MASM to know something about what Windows does with segmentation (e.g. that it happens to pick CS=0x23), it's also reasonable that it knows Windows uses a flat memory model for 32-bit code, CS limit=-1

Comment: Is the goal here just to play around with segmentation?  All `.code` sections will be reachable via offsets in the same x86 segment in a 32-bit flat memory model so you should just be able to do normal calls.  If you want to use segmentation just to play with it, consider using NASM or something.  You can do `call 0x23:label_` in NASM; that assembles + links (into a 32-bit Linux binary where I tested it) to `9a   07 90 04 08   23 00`